# Why is Trisquel Belenos screen brightness always on maximum?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia, brightness, trisquel

I have laptop Acer Aspire intel 4 core and nvidia 910m graphic's card.
Screen brightness is alway's on max, i find on askUbuntu solution for Ubuntu , but these folder's doesn't even exist on my system.
Help?

Comment: I want to have control of my screen brightness  level, my eye's is hurting.

Comment: What is the solution you found on Ubuntu? What graphical environment do you use?

Comment: I think is gnome,     https://askubuntu.com/questions/632698/screen-brightness